# Run `testServer()` w/ `golem::get_golem_options()`

Tags: r, shiny, golem

I have set up a R Shiny app using the [golem](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/golem/index.html) R-package. In the `app_server()` I use some globally set golem options as follows:

```
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {

  myServer(
    id = "test",
    global_variable = golem::get_golem_options()$global_variable,
    other_variable = other_variable
  )

  ...

}
```

Now the default test `testServer()` in `test-golem-recommended.R` throws an error because within `myServer()` it can't find the golem options or the `global_variable` is `NULL` (which also kind of makes sense):

```
testServer(app_server, {

  # Set and test an input
  session$setInputs(x = 2)
  expect_equal(input$x, 2)

})
```

However, is it possible to call `app_server()` so that the golem options are loaded first?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, and have an inelegant solution that involves setting the `golem_options` explicitly during the unit testing phase.

First, I defined a function to set the `golem_options`.  This can be anywhere in your package, or defined in the `testthat` script:

```
#' Set golem options for unit testing purposes
#'
#' @param golem_opts list()
#'
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#'   my_golem_options <-
#'   list(
#'     myconfig = "config01"
#'   )
#'   set_testing_golem_options(my_golem_options)
#' }
set_testing_golem_options <-
  function (golem_opts)
  {
    current_golem_options = getShinyOption("golem_options")
    for (n in names(golem_opts)) {
      current_golem_options[[n]] <- golem_opts[[n]]
    }
    shinyOptions(golem_options = current_golem_options)
  }
```

Then you want to do 3 things just before the `testServer` action in the `test-golem-recommended.R`:

1. Set your `golem_options`:

```
set_testing_golem_options(list(global_variable = 'somevalue'))
```

- Alternatively, you could just make a list of options without the function listed above, but the function will respect any other `shinyOptions` that happen to be already set.

2. Explicitly define the `MockShinySession` that you're going to use for testing:

```
defined_mock_shiny_session <- MockShinySession$new()
```

3. Assign the options into the mock session:

```
defined_mock_shiny_session$options[['golem_options']] <-
  getShinyOption("golem_options")
```

4. Now the trick is to call the `testServer` with the explicit `MockShinySession` that you've just created:

```
testServer(
  app_server, 
  {

    # Set and test an input
    session$setInputs(x = 2)
    expect_equal(input$x, 2)
  },
  session = defined_mock_shiny_session
)
```

That pattern works for me. I should probably explicitly unset any `golem_options` after the test is complete, or ensure that they revert back to their previous state in some way.  But hopefully this will get you unstuck.

Here's everything all in one code block using the example you provided:

```
# Define the function to set golem_options
set_testing_golem_options <-
  function (golem_opts)
  {
    current_golem_options = getShinyOption("golem_options")
    for (n in names(golem_opts)) {
      current_golem_options[[n]] <- golem_opts[[n]]
    }
    shinyOptions(golem_options = current_golem_options)
  }

# Set the golem_options that you need
set_testing_golem_options(list(global_variable = 'somevalue'))

# Create the mock session
defined_mock_shiny_session <- MockShinySession$new()

# Assign the golem_options
defined_mock_shiny_session$options[['golem_options']] <-
  getShinyOption("golem_options")

# Execute the test
testServer(
  app_server, 
  {

    # Set and test an input
    session$setInputs(x = 2)
    expect_equal(input$x, 2)

  },
  session = defined_mock_shiny_session
)
```